# One of my folders wasn't migrated to GitHub and seems to be in a different project for some reason

Tags: git, github

I have a project I've created called DecryptTool, and within it two folders called Backend and Frontend (which each has some code and other files). I wanted to host this project on GitHub, so i made a new repo and ran the git commands they recommended for a new project (adding a readme, remote adding the origin as github.com/myaccount/DecryptionTool.git, etc). However, after running everything, and then doing a git add/commit/push for all the files in my project, the entire backend folder was pushed, and the frontend folder was ignored. The DecyptTool project itself seems to have been accurately pushed, just not 50% of the files. [image: What my project looks like]
[What it looks like in GitHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsptE.png)

I initially noticed that the DecyptTool folder only had one branch, main, (as did the backend folder when I cd into it), but the frontend folder had the branch "master" instead. I ran "git branch -M main" to try to get it noticed, and tried setting the origin to the same url, but it's still ignored. If I add a file to the backend folder, it becomes an unstaged change I can add/commit/push like normal. If i do anything in the frontend folder, it's ignored. A git status shows nothing changed. I have no idea what's causing this. (The .gitignore is inherited from React. I tried deleting it, but it didn't help, so I put it back in)

Edited to add:
Ok, I've now gotten a blank folder with a white arrow to get pushed. I found a hidden .git file in my frontend folder, but even when I deleted it, it didn't notice the change and won't let me add/commit/push it.

Comment: Is there a `.git` directory in `frontend`? If so, it's itself a Git repository, and you have to delete `frontend/.git`.

Comment: I don't see anything like that. The frontend was created using React, i don't know if that's relevant

Comment: If the directories are on different branches, they're almost certainly not part of the same repository. Hard to tele-diagnose, though.

Comment: Ok you were right about the .git, it was a hidden file so I couldn't see it. I've deleted it, but I can't seem to push that change. All of my folders still say the branch is up to date with origin/main. How do i commit that i've deleted the .git file if it's not seeing any changes?

Comment: Check the top-level `.gitignore` to make sure the directory is not ignored, and look at the output of `git status`.

Comment: the git status is just "On branch main. Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'. nothing to commit, working tree clean". It doesn't appear the directory is in the .gitignore, only the stuff automatically populated from React, though i did just run "git check-ignore *" in my frontend folder, and it said "fatal: Pathspec 'README.md' is in submodule 'frontend', so maybe it still thinks frontend is a submodule for some reason?

Comment: Ah, it's a submodule. You probably have a file `.gitmodules` in the top-level directory, which you also want to get rid of.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I got it to work, thank you so much for your help! My problem was (aside from the .git) i needed to run a git rm --cached on it before i could get it to push

Answer (score 2):

the frontend folder is being ignored is that it is listed in your .gitignore file. This is a file that tells Git which files and folders to ignore when tracking changes. If the frontend folder is listed in your .gitignore, then Git will not track any changes to it, and it will not be included in your commits or pushes.

To check if the frontend folder is listed in your .gitignore, run the following command:

```
git ls-files -i --exclude-standard
```

This will list all of the files and folders that are currently ignored by Git. If the frontend folder is listed, then you will need to remove it from the .gitignore file.